# How to "split" long WndProc method to multiple functions?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, winapi

Is there an easy way to split an incredibly long WndProc function to separate functions? I could just literally make functions and call them when processing a specific message but that would mean that I have to pass a lot of arguments over and it would look really messy.

Unfortunately, must use C and raw Win32 only.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static WNDPROC OldWndProc[BUTTON_COUNT];
    static HMENU menu;
    static windowSizeX, windowSizeY;
    //lots more static variables

    switch (message) 
    {
    case WM_SIZE:
        clientX = LOWORD(lParam);
        clientY = HIWORD(lParam);

        si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
        si.fMask = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS;
        si.nMin = 0;
        si.nMax = 1500;
        si.nPage = clientY;
        si.nPos = 0;

        SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);
        return 0;

        // more code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Message Crackers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/83456).

> Typically, a window procedure will handle many messages, with code in the procedure to process each message. This often leads to the source code for a window procedure continuing on for many pages. When an application uses message crackers, almost any window procedure can be listed very concisely. The bulk of the code is transferred to message- handling functions that the message crackers call.

```
   LRESULT _export CALLBACK Template_WndProc(HWND hwnd, WORD msg,
                                             WPARAM wParam,
                                             LPARAM lParam)
   {
       switch (msg)
       {
       HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, Template_OnMouseMove);
       HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, Template_OnLButtonDown);
       HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, Template_OnLButtonDown);
       HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, Template_OnLButtonUp);

       default:
           return Template_DefProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution, as you guessed, is to put the code to handle different messages into different functions. Rather than having a ton of static variables in your WndProc, you should group related variables into structs. Then you can have a few global structs (or static if necessary) which you would pass to the message handling functions that need them.

Comment: Of course, using globals/statics make it impossible to have more than one window associated with a WndProc running (they will end up sharing variables). A better way is to `malloc()` a structure containing the window state and use `SetProp()` or `SetWindowLongPtr()` or even a hash map to associate those structures with their respective `HWND`s.

Comment: @Insilico: Clearly he has only one window now, but your suggestion is the right way to go about refactoring if he ever needs multiple windows handled by the same thread. And I recommend having an internal mapping to associate the structs with HWNDs because then nobody else can change your pointers.